# Front-door criteria - what does the second requirement mean?

Tags: causality, graph-theory, dag

I'm reading *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer* by Pearl, et. al. and I'm a little confused by the definition of front door. The definition in the book (Definition 3.4.1) is:

> A set of variables, **Z** is said to satisfy the front-door criterion relative to an ordered pair of variables **(X, Y)** if:
>
> 1. **Z** intercepts all directed paths from **X** to **Y**
> 2. There is no unblocked path from **X** to **Z**
> 3. All backdoor paths from **Z** to **Y** are blocked by **X**.

I understand the first and third requirements.  But, the second criteria, I'm a little confused.  Here is the situation which confused me. Let's say my causal graph looks like this:

[image: front door criteria question]

So, let's say I set **Z = {B}**. This satisfies criteria 1 (since the only path from **X** to **Y** goes through **B**. This also satisfies criteria 3 (since the only back-door path from **B** to **Y** is **B <-- A <-- X <-- U --> Y** and this is blocked by **X**.

But does it satisfy criteria 2? I think the answer is no because there is an unblocked path from **X** to **Z** namely **X --> A --> B**. As such, my understanding is that I need to make **Z = {A, B}** to satisfy all three criteria. Or am I missing something and do I need to make **Z = {A, B, C}**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criterion 2 is written wrong. It should be:

2. there is no unblocked ***back-door*** path from X to Z

In your diagram, there is an unblocked path from X to Z, but it is not a *back-door* path, which is a path between X and Z that contains an arrow into X.

Comment: It wouldn't have to backdoor; if X and Z both pointed to a conditioned-upon collider, then there would be an unblocked, non-backdoor path that would indeed violate the frontdoor criterion.

Comment: @Noah Are you sure about that? The criterion I gave is a direct quote from Pearl's 2nd edition textbook (Definition 3.3.3 on p. 82)

Comment: Not sure, but the situation I described would yield the same pattern of association as an unblocked backdoor path, so that's why I thought to add it.

Comment: @Jake Westfall  thanks. So, in the example I gave, I could set **Z** to any non-empty subset of **{A, B, C}** right?

Comment: Yes, although the estimation formula would further simplify with two or more elements from {A, B, C}, because of d-separation. @JakeWestfall 's answer is correct, see for example Pearl's "Causality" book, 2nd edition, Definition 3.3.3.

Comment: Thanks!
@Noah I think that what you are saying is correct, but is a different situation from using the front-door. E.g. let's say there was a node **P** and edges from **X --> P** and **B --> P**. In this case, we could ignore **P** and go ahead using the front door adjustment formula. If we did, for some reason, need to adjust for **P**, then we would be in a more complex situation and, I presume, would need do-calculus to figure out what to do.

Comment: @roundsquare oh yes, one wouldn't want to adjust for P, I just wanted to note that you have to assume you are not inadvertently adjusting for P, for example, by selecting units only on one stratum of P (e.g., only participants who were not lost to follow up).